# What is the best way to get an authentication token for openzeppelin defender

Tags: openzeppelin, multisignature, defender

I'm trying to create a proposal using @openzeppelin/defender-admin-client. This is to upgrade a diamond standard contract owned by a multisig. But I keep getting this error message "DefenderApiResponseError: Request failed with status code 403" I'm using hardhat-deploy to manage deploys and have everything set on the defender dashboard